# mounting cifs windows share from HP scanner prompts for password when it shouldn't?

Tags: mount, cifs

I have an HP Officejet 6500 printer/scanner.  I can access the scanner memory card just fine from windows.  Here's what I have set up in Ubuntu 14.04 `fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.101/memory_card /scanner cifs username=Guest,rw 2
```

When I go to `mount /scanner`, I get:

```
# mount /scanner
Password for Guest@//192.168.1.101/memory_card: 
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Clearly, a printer does not have user names or passwords.  Leaving out the username and it uses root.  Anybody gotten this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to adapt this answer from linuxquestions.org to get a working solution: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-to-connect-to-windows-share-without-password-4175580487/

The answer from linuxquestions.org suggests to add the following two options to the mount:

```
nounix,sec=ntlm
```

Using these two options plus the option setting an empty password, I can mount the memory card as follows:

```
mount -t cifs -o nounix,sec=ntlm,password="" //192.168.1.101/memory_card /scanner
```

Or, specifying the mount in the fstab file:

```
//192.168.1.101/memory_card /scanner cifs nounix,sec=ntlm,rw,password="" 2
```